# C++ string and char promotion

Tags: c++, string, char, type-promotion

Say I know the incoming string s only contain one character and i have a data type char c

When I do `s == c`, does c auto converts to a string type or the other way around?

Comment: You should precise if you are talking of C 'string' or C++ std::string

Comment: @manuell. No need to - the question is tagged C++. (And C doesn't really have strings as such, anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, they are incompatible types. Something like this will work:

```
s[0] == c
```

Comment: more accurately: `s.size() == 1 && s[0] == c`

Comment: @Roddy, why should the string change? The question is about comparison

Comment: @BenjaminLindley - The OP: 'Say I know the incoming string s only contain one character'.  Your check `s.size() == 1` totally ignores that precondition, so it's redundant **and therefore wrong**.  Why not check `1 == 1` while you're at it?

Comment: @PaulEvans: It's a judgement call. Checking preconditions is optional but not always "wrong". In this case it avoids dangerous UB when the precondition is broken. If this function is not time-sensitive, it makes sense. An alternative would be to assert or to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant use s ==c  as s would refer to the address 
so you should be using

```
s[0]==c
```

hope it helped